# Density plot of raster stack

Tags: r, r-raster, rastervis

I would like to realize a density plot of raster stack using the package `rasterVis` in R-CRAN.
I would like to change the colors with which the distribution of my raster values is represented and also add a legend. Is it possible to do these things using this package? I didn't find any examples to do it.
Here my example code

```
require(raster)
require(rasterVis)
slogo <- stack(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster")) 
densityplot(slogo,col=c("orange","skyblue1","cyan"))
```

Comment: You can change the color by editing the vector `col`. Some sort of legend is already included in the plot as a label next to the curve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the `rasterVis` functions are based on the `lattice` package. Thus, you should use the `par.settings` argument providing your preferred theme. [Here](http://latticeextra.r-forge.r-project.org/#custom.theme) you will find more information about `lattice` themes.

Regarding your question, try this code:

```
library(rasterVis)
f <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
r <- raster(f)
s <- stack(r, r+500, r-500)
densityplot(s, par.settings = theEconomist.theme)
```

[image: densityplot with Economist theme]